# KSQL: Could I use threads in KSQL UDF functions to speed up the process?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, ksqldb

I'm running independent `ksql-server` in 3-nodes talking to a `Kafka` cluster of 3-nodes. Created a `Stream` from `Topic` with 15 partitions and data is in the Stream for some enrichment. Got a piece of code as `UDF` to do a lookup into the IP2Location.bin file and the `UDF` class looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import io.confluent.common.Configurable;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udf.Udf;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udf.UdfDescription;

@UdfDescription(name = "Ip2Lookup", description = "Lookup class for IP2Location database.")
public class Ip2Lookup implements Configurable {

    private IP2Location loc = null;
    private Gson gson = null;

    @Udf(description = "fetches the geoloc of the ipaddress.")
    public synchronized String ip2lookup(String ip) {

        String json = null;
        if (loc != null) {
            IP2LocationResult result = null;
            try {
                result = loc.query(ip);
                System.out.println(result);
                json = gson.toJson(result);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }
        return ip;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0) {

        try {
            String db_path = null;
            String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

            db_path = "/data/md0/ip2loc/ipv4-bin/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ZIPCODE-TIMEZONE-ISP-DOMAIN-NETSPEED-AREACODE-WEATHER-MOBILE-ELEVATION-USAGETYPE.BIN";

            loc = new IP2Location(db_path);
            gson = new Gson();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Data into the `Topic` and into the `Stream` is pretty fast(may be a million records per second). With `synchronized` in place on the method, the speed is 3000 records/messages per second in each of the `ksql-server` node. With this speed you know, the time its gonna take to catch-up the speed. Without `synchronized` method, I see the corrupt data, as single object/method is used by multiple threads or so.

Question1: How exactly the `udf` call would be called/invoked by KSQL?

Question2: Could I use threads handling the requests in `udf`?

Question3: Being the Topic/Stream is of 15 partitions, should I spin-up 15 nodes of `ksql-servers`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question1: How exactly the udf call would be called/invoked by KSQL?

Not sure what you mean.  Once your UDF is made available to KSQL (see https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html#deploying), you can call the UDF in your KSQL statements as `IP2LOOKUP`.  You can also run `SHOW FUNCTIONS` in KSQL to confirm that your UDF is available for use.

Perhaps you are asking because of your next question? KSQL will call your UDF one message at a time.

> Question2: Could I use threads handling the requests in udf?

Why would you want to do that?  Are you concerned that KSQL, with your current UDF code, would not be able to handle the incoming data volume?  Speaking of which, what *is* the expected data volume that you attempt to handle, because maybe you are trying to do premature optimization?

Also, without knowing more details, I don't think a multi-threaded setup for your UDF would yield any advantages, because the UDF, when called, would still only process one message at a time (per KSQL server or, more precisely, per stream task, of which there can be many per KSQL server; I am mentioning this to make it clear that UDFs in KSQL are *not* bottlenecking your processing by processing only a single message across all servers; the processing is of course distributed and happens in parallel).

> Question3: Being the Topic/Stream is of 15 partitions, should I spin-up 15 nodes of ksql-servers?

This depends on your data volume. You can spin as many or as few KSQL servers as you want.  If the data volume is low, a single KSQL server might suffice. If data volume is higher, you can start launching additional KSQL servers up to a maximum of 15 servers (because the input topic has 15 partitions).  Any additional KSQL servers would be idling.

In the scenario that 15 KSQL servers wouldn't be sufficient, you should increase the number of partitions for your input topic from 15 to a higher number, and then you can also launch more KSQL servers (which thereby increases the compute capacity of your setup).

Comment: Thank you. My bad not framed it right.  “How exactly the udf call would be called/invoked by KSQL?” Should have been, does the ksql call the udf class/method in single object initialisation or multiple objects/threads? I believe I made my point.

Comment: Incoming data volume is 1million messages per sec.

Comment: Data volume: Do a performance benchmark with your current setup of 15 partitions for your input data, and run up to 15 KSQL servers for the benchmark.  If 15 servers aren't sufficient, increase the number of partitions and, subsequently, the number of KSQL servers.

Comment: Well that’s pretty helpful. Thanks. If I start multiple servers on same node, is there a possibility to target start the client cli to monitor the metrics? If not, should I go with new nodes?

Comment: Hm, I don't understand the question. Also, I would suggest to create a new StackOverflow question for this, because the original one is different and was already answered.

Comment: Why using 15 KSQL Server rather than 15 Threads within the KSQL Application ? How Heavy are KSQL Server ?